# Landscape on IBM Power 824s

Tags: power-management, landscape, ibm

Has any one got Landscape standalone working on IBM Power8 824s system?  I have a number of ubuntu 14.0.4.3 and 15.10 vms running but am unable to get Landscape installed on any of them.

Comment: Anyone know if this was fix/can be done in ubuntu 16.04??

Answer (score 0):

I am able to install landscape on both 14.04 and 16.04 releases, and control through Canonical's Landscape web page. What is your issue exactly?

Comment: Sounds like your using the cloud version I am trying to install Landscape local not use the cloud services.

Comment: You mean, you want to deploy a local landspace and use it from your local system?

Comment: Yes, I would like to deploy landscape local like you can on Intel and ARM